# How can I set the rowspan size of a stacklayout within a grid?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms

I have laid out an XML page in Xamarin.Forms which has a "stacklayout" within a "grid".  I want to programmatically set/change the grid rowspan height.

My XML:

```
<Grid x:Name="outerGrid">
    <StackLayout x:Name="MyStackLayout" Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding MyRowSpanValue}" Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- labels/buttons are added here in code-behind -->
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Now in my code-behind, conditionally set it using something like:

```
if (somevar == 2)
    MyRowSpanValue = 5
else
    MyRowSpanValue = 10
```

What is the C# code to do this?  Mine isn't working, even tried putting this into an "OnAppearing()" override.

Thank for any assistance!

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code behind? Specifically looking to see if INotifyPropoertyChanged has been implemented and the MyRowSpanValue property is using it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've not implemented property changed.  Do I need to?  I just want to set this value 1 time upon the page loading based on a condition (or even more simply without the condition and just set the value).  The value will not change thereafter so no changing.

Comment: You'll need it in order to use binding the way you're attempting to. If you're setting it one-and-done in the codebehind, you could try removing the `Grid.RowSpan` from the XAML and only set it in the code behind using the x:Name. Something like `Grid.SetRowSpan(MyStackLayout, 4)`. See the [Xamarin Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#spans) for more details.

Comment: This wound up helping.  I used a "FindByName" on the stacklayout, got a handle to it and then used your "Grid.SetRowSpan(...)" to do this dynamically.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to set your **BindingContext** properly. If you have a view model, you will need to set the binding source in **xaml** as your page so it can find the property.
2. You don't specify any columns in your `grid`, so there is no columns to span for the `StackLayout`
3. If this is in your code behind of the **xaml** file, you don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Just call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyRowSpanValue))`

**EDIT**

**If using ViewModel:**

First you will need an `x:Name="Page"` or whatever name you would like to call your page. Then the code for referencing it will look as follows:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MyStackLayout"
             Grid.Row="5"
             Grid.RowSpan="{Binding MyRowSpanValue, Source={x:Reference Page}}"
             Grid.Column="0">
        <!-- labels/buttons are added here in code-behind -->
</StackLayout>
```

**Not using a ViewModel**

In your page constructor, set the `BindingContext=this;` and then the xaml/page will look to your code behind for the **MyRowSpanValue** property.

```
public YourConstructor()
{
    BindingContext = this; // Code behind will be binding context for XAML
}
```

When you want to change the value of the property (**used for both situations**)

```
public int MyRowSpanValue { get; set; }

// When you want to change the MyRowSpanProperty
public void ChangeTheValue()
{
    MyRowSpanValue = 3; // Or whatever value you are wanting
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyRowSpanValue));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response.  I am not using a view model here, but I did try setting a BindingContext - but wasn't sure to what it should be set.  Per the response above, I was able to get accomplished what I needed, but I would be very interested in actual code to set the proper context in this scenario for future reference.

Comment: @Donna Edited my answer with some code snippets with/without a ViewModel to bind to your property.

Comment: I'm confused on the use of "Page".  The stacklayout you exemplified has "MyStackLayout"; then the reference ("x:Reference...") refers to "Page".  Is "Page" in the reference of the souce a keyword or should that read something else?  Once I do the bindingcontext line in code-behind, would another line be to then access "MyRowSpanValue = 4" or something?

Comment: Sorry, that `x:Name=Page` would need to be towards the top of your **xaml** on your `ContentPage`. Since you don't have a VM though, in the code behind of your xaml, when you want to set `MyRowSpanValue`, use `MyRowSpanValue = <value>;` and then call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyRowSpanValue));`

Comment: Great - thanks so much for the help (from Andrew as well).